# Odd rendering issue -- Extra lines

Tags: rendering, vertices

When I render one of my models in my app, black lines (which I did not draw) are getting rendered which run from various points on my model all to a single point.  Please see image.  As I move my camera around in the app, the single point moves around (and in turn the destination of the lines).  What are these black lines, what are they pointing to, and how do I fix?

[image: model with black lines]

[image: enter mesh issues in blender]

[image: another view in blender]

Note: Blender newbie here

Thanks

Edit new photo showing mesh issues in blender too.  Removed reference to libgdx to remove confusion.

Comment: If it renders well in Blender, it should be asked to libGdx support perhaps...

Comment: all my other models are rendering well in libgdx so I don't think it's a problem there.  I believe it's a problem with the model itself.  Perhaps a vertex that's off or something.

Comment: Well I guess most users here don't use or even know what libGdx is, so unless you provide a blendfile we can look at and check for any errors I don't think you'll be able to get many quality answers here

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't seem to be a question about Blender or an issue caused by Blender

Comment: It doesn't have to do with LibGdx.  I regret mentioning it :)  I wish I could post my blender file but that would violate company policy.  Definitely mesh issues.

Comment: Found mesh issues in the model in Blender which appear like they might be related.  I'm posting a new picture.  Notice how some meshes show black lines in the blender picture?  Thinking they're the same black lines in the render.  Agree?  If so, how to fix?

Comment: posted a second screenshot in blender.  this time in object mode (first was in edit).

Comment: You might want to upload your .blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ , then adding the given link your question above to receive a good answer. Otherwise than that, this seems to be caused by z-fighting due to double geometry. Go to edit mode, hit "A" to select everything, then "W" and "Remove Doubles".

Comment: Interesting thanks.  Unfortunately I'm not legally allowed to upload this file, however it does seem to be related.  It fixed it in a number of places, but perhaps more interesting it seems to have caused a new area to pop up with it.  A new spot to investigate.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I didn't determine the exact issue for all situations, but it seemed some meshes had doubles issues, faces issues, normals issues, etc.  You could do things like select a vertex around a bad area and hit Ctrl+ to select similar ones, but the bad one wouldn't get selected.

To fix, I ended up selecting whole areas that were at issue and deleting them.  I then either rebuilt them or duplicated other similar areas and placing them there.

I hate not knowing the exact issue, but at least I'm up and running.

Thanks to those who took the time!